# How are the densities of the negative and positive variation related to the density of the total variation of a signed measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a finite signed measure space and $(\mu^+,\mu^-)$ denote the Jordan decomposition of $\mu$, i.e. $$\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-\tag1$$ and $\mu^\pm$ is singular in respect to $\mu^\mp$. Now, let $$|\mu|:=\mu^++\mu^-\;.$$ Suppose $\mu^\pm$ is absolute continuous with respect to a $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$. By the Radon–Nikodym theorem, $\mu^\pm$ has a density with respect to $\nu$, i.e. $$\mu^\pm(A)=\int_A\phi^\pm\:{\rm d}\nu\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal A\tag2$$ for some $\mathcal A$-measurable $\phi^\pm:\Omega\to[0,\infty)$.

> Obviously, $\mu$ and $|\mu|$ have densities with respect to $\nu$ too. How are these densities related to $\phi^\pm$?

In particular, it's clear that $$\mu(A)=\int_A\underbrace{\phi^+-\phi^-}_{=:\:\phi}\:{\rm d}\nu\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal A\tag3$$ by $(1)$, i.e. the density of $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$ is $\phi=\phi^+-\phi^-$.

> Now, I've found a proof where the author seems to use that the density of $|\mu|$ with respect to $\nu$ is $|\phi|$. How can we show that?

Comment: At the very end of your post, do you mean $|\phi|$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, of course. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice of notation $\phi^\pm$ seems bad in this moment, because it assumes that you already know how the [positive and negative partes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts) of the densites relate to each other.

First fact to have in mind is that $\mu \ll \nu$ if and only if $\mu^\pm \ll \nu$, if and only if $|\mu| \ll \nu$, so all relevant Radon-Nikodym derivatives exist, since $\mu$ is finite. And Radon-Nikodym derivatives satisfy the sum rule, so $$\mu = \mu^+ - \mu^- \implies \frac{\rm d\mu}{\rm d \nu} = \frac{\rm d\mu^+}{\rm d \nu}-\frac{\rm d\mu^-}{\rm d \nu}.$$ and on the other hand$$|\mu| = \mu^+ + \mu^- \implies \frac{\rm d|\mu|}{\rm d \nu} = \frac{\rm d\mu^+}{\rm d \nu}+\frac{\rm d\mu^-}{\rm d \nu}.$$Once we check that $$\left(\frac{\rm d\mu}{\rm d \nu} \right)^\pm = \frac{\rm d\mu^\pm}{\rm d\nu},$$it will follow that $$\left|\frac{\rm d\mu}{\rm d \nu} \right| = \frac{\rm d|\mu|}{\rm d\nu}$$too, from the above. We use the $\nu$-a.e. uniqueness in the Radon-Nikodym theorem. Let $(P,N)$ be a Hahn-decomposition of $\Omega$. Given $E \in \mathcal{A}$, we have $$\mu^+(E) = \mu(E \cap P) = \int_{E\cap P} \frac{\rm d\mu}{\rm d\nu}\,{\rm d}\nu = \int_{E \cap P} \left(\frac{\rm d\mu}{\rm d\nu}\right)^+\,{\rm d}\nu = \int_E\left(\frac{\rm d\mu}{\rm d \nu} \right)^+\,{\rm d}\nu,$$since in the last step we use $\mu^+ \perp \mu^-$. So $({\rm d}\mu/{\rm d}\nu)^+ = {\rm d}\mu^+/{\rm d}\nu$, and the other is analogous.

Comment: I think $\nu$ needs to be $\sigma$-finite in order to ensure the existence of the Radon-Nikodym derivatives. I've added that to the question.

Comment: I guess you define $f^\pm:=\max(\pm f,0)$, right?

Comment: Ah yes, I thought we had that already, my bad. And that's the definition of $f^+$ alright.

Comment: I guess it's easy, but I don't see how we need to verify that $$\int_{E\cap P} \frac{\rm d\mu}{\rm d\nu}\,{\rm d}\nu = \int_{E \cap P} \left(\frac{\rm d\mu}{\rm d\nu}\right)^+\,{\rm d}\nu\;.$$

Comment: It is because we're integrating over $P$ and $({\rm d \mu^-}/{\rm d \nu})|_P=0$

Comment: That doesn't yield the equality. Did you mean $\left.({\rm d}\mu/{\rm d}\nu)^-\right|_P=0$?

Comment: Ah!! Sorry, yes, that's what I meant (can't edit the previous comment anymore, though)

Comment: And how do you prove that? I guess your argumentation is the following: Let $f:={\rm d}\mu/{\rm d}\nu$. Then, $$\int_A1_{\Omega^+}f\:{\rm d}\nu=\int_{A\:\cap\:\Omega^+}f\:{\rm d}\nu=\mu(A\cap\Omega^+)\ge0\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal A$$ and hence $$1_{\Omega^+f}\ge0\;\;\;\nu\text{-almost everywhere}\;.$$ Analogously, $$1_{\Omega^-f}\le0\;\;\;\nu\text{-almost everywhere}\;.$$ Thus, $$f^\pm=1_{\Omega^\pm}f\;\;\;\nu\text{-almost everywhere}$$ and hence $$1_{\Omega^\mp}f^\pm=1_{\Omega^\mp}(1_{\Omega^\pm}f)=0\;\;\;\nu\text{-almost everywhere}\;.$$